# how to write java servelt relative file path

Tags: java, servlets, path, servlet-3.0

i am using SERVLET and i am reading from XML files i want to read the XML files using relative or dynamic paths , i tried the `"./directoryName"` and the `"fileName"` but non of these worked 
my path now loooks like this :

```
public static final String DEFAULT_INFO_FILES_PATH = "D:/dev/workspace/QwiltSim/src/ps/exalt/qwilt/ui/sim/DevicesInfo.xml";
```

i want it to be some thing like :

```
 public static final String DEFAULT_INFO_FILES_PATH = SomeFolderName+"DevicesInfo.xml"
```

can any one help me please ?

Comment: I'd consider putting it in my classpath and reading it as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

[`ServletContext#getRealPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)) converts relative paths within your application to file system paths. If your XMLs are static and you deploy them along with your servlet application, you can store them within the WAR and resolve the path to them using this method.